# Find Duplicate value in array based on specific column using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table containing this three field , nodes, Memeber_id, id .there is two repetitive rows of id in entire  table.  Based on this id value in id column I want to find repetitive value in node array.
for eg .  -169116 id  represents two nodes array {-167486,-49628} and {-43815,-49625,-49626,-49627,-49628}
 In both the array common value is  -49628.
so it should select -169116 id and -49628 value from array.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the array and then simply group by count(node) > 1:

```
select node, id, count(*) 
from (select unnest(nodes) as node, member_id, id from node_test) as g
group by node, id having count(node) > 1;
```

This results in:

```
  node  |   id    | count
--------+---------+-------
 -49628 | -169116 |     2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted  @Julia Leder. Thank you